# C++, .NET and NuGet download compiling but not linking

Tags: c++, .net, nuget

OK I knew it would be messy but I want to access
System.Management.Automation
from C++. Legacy stuff.
Particularly I want to pipeline stuff through PowerShell.

Using VS2022 [my project] | Add | Reference I can find the package and hit Install and it puts it in the packages.config file.
Net result nothing.

If I Add | Reference | Browse to the DLL and add that I can get the namespaces so my code compiles but when I run it it bitches about

System.IO.FileLoadException
HResult=0x8013141A
Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=7.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)
Inner Exception 1:
SecurityException: Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)

If I copy the DLL into every relevant folder on the project still no good.
I'm a long served C/C++ programmer but NuGet in C++ is new ground for me
Obviously I've missed a step but I can't figure it.
Google finds me 1000001 people doing it in C# but no C++ example. Please help an old man out.

Comment: Please change the title of your question to be understandable of the particular problem that you're having.

Comment: That nuget package must only be used in a project that targets .net6.  At runtime it probably loads the assembly from the GAC and will find a mismatch.  Add the reference from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\etc instead.

Comment: Thanks. Naturally I can't get 7.0 as that hasn't tunnelled its way to C++ yet but if I use an older  version I might get a match. That has moved me forwards.